# Cronjobs - can webhoster disable them?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, web-hosting

I want to host a private browsergame that creates cronjobs via PHP script to maintain the MySQL database and looking for a webhoster I found Strato.

Strato lists Cronjobs as a feature that not every package includes.
It provides some kind of web interface to manage cronjobs.

I wonder if it is possible that the hoster disables the cronjobs my browsergame would create or if the feature is only about the web interface created cronjobs.

Can somebody answer that?

Answer (score 0):

Typically software like that is a webhosting platform (i.e. Plesk, CPanel, etc). They run a segmented interface for your end users to go in and do things like setup websites, cron jobs, etc. It's possible that the server owner could turn your cron job off, but unlikely as they could lose your business.

Comment: Well, Strato is pretty huge here (Germany) and I'm not a customer yet.
The cronjobs of the browsergame are somehow created by PHP script. I'm not sure if they can be blocked by Strato or if the feature "Cronjobs" they sell is only about the web interface to create Cronjobs.

Comment: If I were you, then, I would get a virtual server where you have complete control over any and all cron jobs. I know 1and1 has a German datacenter and sells virtual servers monthly. There are probably others as well.

Comment: A virtual server is too expensive and I don't really need one.
I never had any problems with cronjobs and any hosters yet, it just made me wonder why they state it as an extra feature.
The game is pretty small. Like 30 players max.